# imagemagick for thumbnail

Tags: php, imagemagick

I would like user to upload most of their photo albums online, would it feasible to create and save one in thumbnails folder and one in full size folder or generate thumbnails on the fly when the user access their album? It will be something like eBay does. Webspace is not a concern since I have an unlimited plan.

Answer (score 1):

Store the thumbnails when they're uploaded, or better yet, create a thumbnail **(and store it)** when the image is first accessed.

Storing them means that the server won't have to do unnecessary processing on every page load.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it help to lighten server load.